# How to clear the ModifiedProperties of an ADObject

Tags: powershell, properties, active-directory

None of the code below clears the 'ModifiedProperties' property and the last thing i want to do is re-retrieve the ADObject (+40000 users)

Impossible or anyone knows how ?

Code :

```bsh
# Get a user and modify a property
$ADUser = Get-ADUser 'user1' -Properties title
$ADUser.title = 'TEST'

$ADUser.ModifiedProperties # shows Title

# Save changes to AD - expecting the ModifiedProperties would reset
Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser
$ADUser.ModifiedProperties # still shows Title

$ADUser.psobject.Properties.Remove("ModifiedProperties")

$ADUser.psobject.Members.Remove('ModifiedProperties')

$ADUser.ModifiedProperties.Clear()
$ADUser.ModifiedProperties.Remove('Title') | Out-Null

$ADUser.psobject.BaseObject.ModifiedProperties.Clear()
$ADUser.psobject.BaseObject.ModifiedProperties.Remove('Title') | Out-Null

$ADUser.ModifiedProperties # still shows Title
```

This works, but only retrieves the default properties - no 'Title'

```bsh
# Save changes to AD with -PassTru
$ADUser = Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser -PassThru
$ADUser.ModifiedProperties
```

Comment: You don't need to do `Get-ADUser` in order to do `Set-ADUser`. You can do this with `Set-Aduser 'user1' -Title 'New title'; Get-ADUser 'user1' -properties title`. There is only one retrieval that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually the script i posted is stripped down to the basics. There is more processing, testing, validation on the ADUser before the title attribute is set. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using `-PassThru` doesn't give you the additional properties, and it doesn't have a `-Properties` parameter, you have to use `Get-ADUser`.

You *could* pipe the result of `Set-ADUser` into `Get-ADUser`, like this:

```
$ADUser = (Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser -PassThru | Get-ADUser -Properties title)
```

But that creates more traffic than necessary because `Set-ADUser`, when used with `-PassThru`, actually does a two operations: a set and a get. I confirmed this by watching the network traffic while doing this.

So if you pipe the result into `Get-ADUser`, you end up doing 3 operations: a set, a get, then another get.

So you're better off just repeating the original `Get-ADUser` after the `Set-ADUser`.

For example:

```
# Get a user and modify a property
$ADUser = Get-ADUser 'user1' -Properties title
$ADUser.title = 'TEST'

$ADUser.ModifiedProperties # shows Title

# Save changes to AD - expecting the ModifiedProperties would reset
Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser
$ADUser = Get-ADUser $ADUser -Properties title
$ADUser.ModifiedProperties # shows nothing
```

Comment: It seems indeed like it's not possible. I did some more research and found out that the 'ModifiedProperties' is a read-only property that can't be changed.
So Set-ADUser and then retrieve with Get-ADUser is the only way. thank you